# How to access the Playground GUI?

Tags: weaviate

What would be the url to access the Playground GUI in weaviate?
I would like to explore and visualize some GraphQL queries.

I have read the playground documentation/readme but that does not specify how to access the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the playground at http://playground.semi.technology. It is not served on https on purpose, so that you can connect it with a locally running http instance as well without running into "mixed content" issues.

The playground runs completely in your browser (React-based SPA), so you can connect it to remote instances or local instances by entering a local URL (e.g. `http://localhost:8080/v1/graphql`) into the text field on the start page.

As of now the playground only supports the most current version of Weaviate (which at the time of writing this is `0.19.x`).

> I have read the playground documentation/readme but that does not specify how to access the GUI.

The documentation is currently being overhauled and will soon have a strong focus on a smooth "Getting Started" experience. Unfortunately that's not the case yet ;-)

Comment: The link does not work. This seems to be outdated.

Comment: Very out of date indeed! After poking around a bit, the closest thing I found was in https://console.weaviate.cloud/dashboard you can click the "query" button by your database to find a GUI. That's for Weaviate Cloud, I don't know what you'd do if you weren't using Cloud.